# How to multiply thousands in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

```js
function multiplicar() {
  m1 = document.getElementById("multiplicando").value;
  m2 = document.getElementById("multiplicador").value;

  m3 = m2 * 0.01;
  x = m3 * parseFloat(m1);
  x1 = x - 2380000;

  document.getElementById("resultado").value = x1.toLocaleString();
}
const numberWithCommas = (x) => {
  return x.toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");
}

function Sumar() {
  var n1 = 1;
  var n2 = document.getElementById('multiplicador').value;
  var suma = parseInt(n1) + parseInt(n2);
  document.getElementById("multiplicador").value = suma;
  multiplicar();
}

function resta() {
  var r1 = 1;
  var r2 = document.getElementById('multiplicador').value;
  var resta = parseInt(r2) - parseInt(r1);
  document.getElementById("multiplicador").value = resta;
  multiplicar();
}
```

```html
<form id="multiplicar">
  <div class="container-block">
      <label>$</label> <input type="text" name="multiplicando" id="multiplicando" value="300000000" onChange="multiplicar();" onkeydown="noPuntoComa( event )" placeholder="Escribe el valor">
  </div>

  <div class="container-block">
    <input type="button" onclick="resta();" value="-" class="resta">
    <div class="container-input">
      <input type="text" name="multiplicador" id="multiplicador" value="3" onChange="multiplicar();" onkeyUp="multiplicar();" min="0" pattern="^[0-9]+">
      <label style="    right: 130px;">%</label>
    </div>
    <input type="button" onclick="Sumar();" value="+" class="suma">
  </div>

  <div class="container-block-resultado">
      <label>$</label> <input type="text" id="resultado">
  </div>

</form>
```

I am learning a bit of javascript, i want to make a a small mathematical operation using thousands. Example: 300,000,000 * 3% = 900,000 This is what you should be displayed to the user, and the user may be able to raise or lower the percentage or value as is as a calculator, and I cannot find how to do to multiply a number with thousands by the percentage in javascript.

Comment: So you can not do `300000000 * .03`? remove the commas, convert to a number, add the commas back.

Comment: Hello, but at the time of print would show a whole number and i want you to display the result 300,000,000 by the separate point.

Thanks

Comment: @epascarello Thanks

Comment: There is a difference between what you display to the user and how you represent values internally. You may want to display the number with the commas but internally you do not need them. Look up number literals to see how to represent numbers in JavaScript and Number formatting to see how to display the numbers.

Answer (score 3):

So convert your strings to numbers. Remove commas and convert to a number. Convert the percentage into a decimal number. Add add the commas back when you want to display it.

```js
function removeComma (str) {
  return Number(str.replace(/,/g, ''))
}
function makePercentage (str) {
  return Number(str.replace(/%/, '')) / 100
}
function addCommas (number) {
  return number.toLocaleString()
}

var str1 = "300,000,000"
var str2 = "3%"

var mathResult = removeComma(str1) * makePercentage(str2)
var result = addCommas(mathResult)

console.log(result)
```

Comment: When making the percentage, replacing `%` and converting to number works, but I think this is one of the occasions when `parseInt` is better, as getting the initial numbers is exactly what it's suited for. On the other hand, I also like that `removeComma` and `makePercentage` are doing the same thing.

Comment: @epascarello, 
How could mostar the result in a html tag, and it is possible at the time of the result I can add a subtraction?

Example:
var str1 = "300,000,000"
var str2 = "3%"
var str3 = "2,380,000"
var mathResult = removeComma(str1) * makePercentage(str2)
var resta = removeComma(mathResult) - removeComma(str3)

var result = addCommas(resta)

Comment: @VLAZ and when it is `3.2%` ?

Comment: How to add it to an element? Set the textContent, innerHTML, or value?

Comment: @epascarello good point, `parseFloat` would be even more relevant

Answer (score 0):

> Javascript have limitation, so in that case the max safe integer is
>   2147483647. Also have some library that handle big int value calculation BigNumber.js.

I would recommend using integers, though if you need to work with very large integers I would suggest using a big number or big integer library such as one of these:

http://jsfromhell.com/classes/bignumber
https://silentmatt.com/biginteger/
The downside is you have to use these number objects and their methods rather than the primitive Number type and standard JS operators, but you'll have a lot more flexibility with operating on large numbers.